# How to make a link button at the center of a panel in asp.net ?

Tags: asp.net, css

I am developing a asp.net applicaiton using IE6. I need to insert a link button inside a panel in such a way that the link should be at the center of the panel (both horizontally and vertically). I am using following code

```
    <table>
            <tr>

                <td>
                    <asp:Panel ID="panel1" runat="server" CssClass="panelCss">

                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LintButton_SubmitRequst" runat="server"
                         CssClass="linkbuttonCss"> Submit Request
                        </asp:LinkButton>

                   </asp:Panel>


                </td>


            </tr>
        </table>
```

CSS:

```
 .panelCss
{
 background-color:#5483C6;   
 height:50px; 
 width: 100px;
 text-align:center;
 vertical-align: middle;

}

.linkbuttonCss
{
color: Black;
font-size: large; 
vertical-align: middle;
font-size: 10px;
}
```

Link button is always staying at the top position of panel. Can someone tell be how to bring it to center (both horizontally and vertically) ?

Answer (score 0):

Since your panel have a fixed height, you could use padding :

```
 .panelCss
{
 background-color:#5483C6;   
 height:50px; 
 width: 100px;
 vertical-align: middle;
 padding-top: 20px;
}
```

I don't have IE6 at hand to test. Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ghb8c/). I just wonder why targeting this browser?

More info about [vertical-align](http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
            <tr>

                <td Class="panelCss">

<asp:Panel ID="panel1" runat="server">

                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LintButton_SubmitRequst" runat="server"
                         CssClass="linkbuttonCss"> Submit Request
                        </asp:LinkButton>
</asp:Panel>




                </td>


            </tr>
        </table>
```

Move panelCss to the td element of your table.